# Value changes using mov from a register to an array

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86

When I attempt to move a value from the `BX` register to an array element, the value changes completely.
Let's say for example that my array is {0,4,4}, the `SI` register is equal to 1, and *colorNum* = 3 (*colorNum* and the array are both in word size).

```
mov bx, [colorNum]
mov [arr + si], bx
```

Following this, I could see in the debugger that the array is now: {769,0,4}
I simply don't know what went wrong, as it should have been: {0,3,4}

What should I change in order to move the proper value to the array?

Comment: If each element is a WORD, `si` must be 2 to store to the second element. Are you sure the original array was not `{1, 4, 4}`? that would explain the `{769,0,4}`

Comment: What if `si` is correct and it is already `2*index`? It is impossible to see if this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `arr + si` is equivalent to `(char*)arr+1`.

Let's assume that the size of `word` is 2: with `mov [arr + si], bx`, you are writing a `word` value into the second half of the first cell of the array and the first half of the second cell of the array.

So you need to replace `arr + si` with an expression equivalent to `(char*)arr+1*sizeof(word)`.

Comment: `arr + si*2` is not a valid 16 bit addressing mode. Since the question has the *assembly* tag, it would be nice to provide some correct assembly code :)

Comment: @MargaretBloom: I agree, I initially wrote only "you need to use an expression equivalent to `(char*)arr+1*sizeof(word)`". I will revert that, thank you for pointing it out...